# Problem with setting up ChatObject[]: possible conflict?

Tags: configuration, llm

**Context**

My naive expectation is that in order to use `chat = ChatObject[]` in Mathematica 13.3.1 I don't need to have a paid plan with OpenAI.

**Question**

> Is this correct?

**Attempt**

When I try

```
 chat = ChatObject[]
```

[image]

and then

```
 ChatEvaluate[chat, "What's the tallest mountain?"]
```

I get

[image]

---

Following some suggestions, I tried

```
SystemCredential[
  "OPENAI_API_KEY"] = 
"sk-B3N*e5p"
```

But it did not change the response.

I also tried creating a new key [following this post](https://elephas.app/blog/how-to-get-chatgpt-api-key-clh93ii2e1642073tpacu6w934j) but it did not help.

Is there a mean to restore the default behaviour of Mathematica?

---

Finally note that this applies to all LLM functions:

```
  ImageSynthesize["A painting of a ram in the style of Monet"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me record here the answer I got on the chat.
As @RohitNamjoshi @kirkus explained to me, when you create an OpenAI account, you get some number of free API calls over 30 days. After that, **you have to provide a credit card** which will be charged for API usage. Do that, create a new key and use it.

I  naively expected that WRI would cover this: its a bit unfortunate IMHO to highlight as novelty of a new version something which is only temporally accessible without extra cost. May be I did not read the documentation well enough.

This is also discussed [here](https://%20https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2946932).